# Gps module has to use the UART pins

Tags: python, gps, uart, xbee

The problem is that the Gps module has to use the UART pins that are already connected to the Xbee. What i can do? (I use raspberry pi zero)

I tried this code.
from gpiozero import DigitalOutputDevice, DigitalInputDevice
import time

gps_tx_pin = 17  # GPIO pin connected to the TX pin of the GPS module
gps_rx_pin = 26  # GPIO pin connected to the RX pin of the GPS module

gps_tx = DigitalOutputDevice(gps_tx_pin)
gps_rx = DigitalInputDevice(gps_rx_pin)

def gps_write(data):
for char in data:
binary = bin(ord(char))[2:].zfill(8)  # Convert character to binary string
for bit in binary:
gps_tx.value = int(bit)
time.sleep(0.01)  # Adjust the delay as per the requirements

def gps_read():
data = ""
while True:
if gps_rx.value:
data += "1"
else:
data += "0"
time.sleep(0.01)  # Adjust the delay as per the requirements
if len(data) >= 8:  # Adjust the number of bits received per character
break
return data
while True:
gps_write("AT\r\n")  # Send command to GPS module
response = gps_read()  # Read response from GPS module

```
response_char = chr(int(response, 2))  # Convert binary string to ASCII character

if response_char.startswith("$GPGGA"):
    data_parts = response_char.split(",")
    if len(data_parts) >= 10:
        latitude = data_parts[2]
        longitude = data_parts[4]
        print("Latitude: {}".format(latitude))
        print("Longitude: {}".format(longitude))

time.sleep(1)  # Adjust the delay as per the requirements
```

Comment: `chr(int(response, 2))` seems suspicious. Note: you have a char, not a string. But why do you get a binary string?

Comment: what i should do?